# Using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to access test resources

Tags: spring

In my IntelliJ project, under the project root, there is a config folder.
This is where various `.properties` files are located.
Within the application, these are made available to Spring in the standard way, using a `propertiesConfigurer.xml` file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
         <value>file:config/${name}.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
   <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

The reason they are accessed using 'file', is that eventually they may be external to the deployed jar.
This works, both when running the application, and when running unit tests.

I also wish to access files which are only for use when running tests.
I have placed these under:

```
test
--- resources
-------META-INF
----------spring
-------------config
```

I have added this line to the list of locations within the same `propertiesConfigurer.xml`:

```
<value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/config/${name}.properties</value>
```

This is not working. No file or resource exception is being thrown, but none of the properties defined in the test file are being resolved within the application.

Within the IntelliJ Project Settings->Modules, src\test\resources is listed as a context root.
Also, on the file system, under:

```
...\target\test-classes\META-INF\spring\config
```

the test property files exist.

What is the correct way to access them?

Thanks

Comment: Remove "*" from value after classpath.

Comment: Now throws a FileNotFoundException ... cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Right. Is your test/resources in classpath?

Comment: The following is in the pom:         <testResources>
          <testResource>
              <targetPath>.</targetPath>
           <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
          </testResource>
        </testResources>